# Why the spring-cloud with the gatway ignore the cors property defined in application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to build a microservices spring-boot application using spring-cloud and spring-gateway. In my application there is a api-gateway application that handle all the request and later will dispatch those request to the right microservice.

For the front-end I'm using angular and for test the endpoints I'm using postman. At the moment I'm having a CORS problem. I've configured the api-gateway in this way:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping=true
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedOrigins=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedHeaders=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowedMethods=*
```

According to the documentation it should be enough to allow a client to make a request without problem.

Also I've configured all the gateway route in this way...

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].id=entity-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].uri=lb://entity-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].predicates[0]=Path=/api/entity/hello
```

My security config also is the one below

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebFluxSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
            @Bean
            public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity) {
                serverHttpSecurity
                        .authorizeExchange(exchange ->
                                exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**")
                                        .permitAll()
                                        .anyExchange()
                                        .authenticated())
                        .cors()
                        .and()
                        .csrf()
                        .disable()
                        .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt);
                return serverHttpSecurity.build();
            }
        }
```

Said that, if for instance I make a request with postman to the path `/api/entity/hello` I get the correct response. If I'm using the angular client and try to access an end-point , first an OPTIONS preflight request is made and return:

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/entity/hello. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 401.*

then the GET request for the `..../hello` path is made and the result is the same.

I am using spring-boot 2.7.3 and the latest spring-boot-cloud and gateway package.

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks to all

Comment: This is not related to angular, please remove the tag accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try adding CorsConfigurationSource bean to your config class.

```
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(GlobalCorsProperties globalCorsProperties) {
    var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    globalCorsProperties.getCorsConfigurations().forEach(source::registerCorsConfiguration);
    return source;
}
```